# getting the total line count from subprocess.popen

Tags: python, python-2.7

Considering the following example:

```
P1 = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    P1.stdout.readLines()
```

In the above example , is it possible to count the number of lines as output from the p1?because I can iterate line by line by using p1.stdout.readLines(),

but that’s not what I want , I need the total number of lines as output… Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Use `len()` e.g:

```
lines = P1.stdout.readLines()
no_of_lines = len(lines)
```

Or you can simply just do:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> p = Popen(["ls", "-1", "/usr/local/bin"], stdout=PIPE)
>>> sum(1 for _ in p.stdout)
493
```

*This method is a bit different to `len()` as it consumes a generator expressions and aums it up. i.e: Give me the sum of a sequence of 1's for every line in p1.stdout*.

A lot of objects in Python that support iteration also support the `len()` function.

- list
- dict
- set
- unicode/str/bytes

These objects all implement `__len__` which `len()` uses.

This is called [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and is one of the most useful typing disciplines of Python!